# Can't see branches in gitweb installation

Tags: git, gitweb

I'm running gitweb without anything like gitolite or gitosis or whatever.

My project is showing up fine, but none of my branches are. I can only see "master".

Is there some kind of file I need to edit in order to show this?

Here's the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf
    ServerName git.server.be
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/gitweb
    AliasMatch ^(/.*?)(\.git)(/.*)? /home/gitadmin$1$3
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitweb setup isn't showing you branches because of your apache config file.  You are just not seeing that there is a section called tags and heads on the summary page for your projects.

From there, you should be able to select a tag or a branch you want to view, and see those commits within that branch.  However, I don't see what some people expect and get out of gitk, where you can see all branches and their commits in a unified view.  I also don't see a visual indicator anywhere on the commit itself which tells you what branch any commmit is on, when viewing said commit.

Hope this helps, and I hope this is accurate for your gitweb install.